# Do I have to provision a paid database in IBM cloud in order to use Watson OpenScale's features?

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-openscale

Watson OpenScale provides free internal database in the tutorial. However, if I want to monitor my own models, do I need to provision a paid database in IBM cloud to do the payload logging?

If not, does the free internal database also support the payload data analytics?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for interested in WOS. You can monitor your own models even if you're using Lite plan(Free) with internal DB. see catalog https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/watson-openscale for limitations.I suppose the limitation is mainly for capacity/sizing , not for functional restriction. Have Fun.

Comment: @ishida330 please don't answer in comments; make this a proper answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use freely the internal database for monitoring of any model type with the limitations listed at: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/ai-openscale?topic=ai-openscale-connect-db#cdb-lite.

In summary:

- The free database is hosted, and is not directly accessible to you.
- The database capacity is limited to 1GB.
- IBM® Watson OpenScale will have full access to your database, and thus will have full access to your data.
- The database is not GDPR-compliant. If your model processes personally-identifiable information (PII), you cannot use the free database.